# Express: Finding the controller for a URL

Tags: express

I have an Express app. One aspect that I find slightly frustrating is that given a URL for my app, have to manually look through the routers to determine where it ends up.

Is there a function that can determine this for me or is there a way I can write a function to accomplish this?

Comment: This is not something that Express has support for and not something it is designed to be used for.  You'd have to dive into the non-public and non-documented internals of Express to try to find out which route handlers match a given URL.  You'll have to familiarize yourself with the internals of routers and layers.

Comment: I don't know why you find this frustrating.  You define your routes explicitly so that Express, not you, will do the routing.  It stores all your defined routes in its own internal data structures and then walks through them to see which ones match an incoming http request path.  What problem are you actually trying to solve here?  Why are you trying to do human routing?

Comment: FYI, if you're trying to figure out which controller is executing for a given URL, then perhaps you should put some logging into your controllers that can be turned on/off with a debug flag.  Then, when you need to know something like this, you can turn the debug flag on and get the extra logging.  You could also set a debugger breakpoint in some early middleware and then step through the routing engine and see what controller it decides matches and it calls.

Comment: @jsfriend00: Yeah, logging is a good solution for dev, but not so much for production such as if someone tells me they are encountering an error at a specific URL

Comment: How can YOU not know what route is supposed to match a given URL?  Don't you have the files where your routes are defined?  It should not take long to see which one will match a given URL just by code inspection.  You shouldn't have lots of conflicting routes that would make this complicated.